# TouchPad & WiFi not working on Lenovo Miix 2 (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 15.10, 16.04

I have a Lenovo Miix 2 Windows Tablet. I am interested in doing Linux on it.

I have booted a LiveUSB (Linux Mint/Ubuntu Mate - 16.04) and both in both distros, the TouchPad and WiFi doesn't work.

I can't find any related threads that related to my situation, can someone help me out please?

Steve

Comment: Is it possible to run ubuntu or different newer linux on this tablet?

Answer (score 0):

To get the wifi working, you just need to remove the ideapad_laptop module

enter the following in the terminal window:

`sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop`

When I know how to get the touch pad running i let you know.